# Is there a git command that will output the contents of a file as it is in the index?

Tags: git

Is there a git command that will output the contents of a file as it is in the index? In other words, the other file used in `git diff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
git show :<filename>
```

See the entry on `<rev>:<path>` under [Specifying Revisions](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) in the [gitrevisions man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrevisions.html).